# The actual name of growth force

Tags: botany, growth

I see how large trees and weeds that are capable of splitting concrete, and realized that I have no idea what this phenomenon is officially called. Google was no help, suggesting root pressure, but that's an interior force for water and sugar transport, not what I was looking for. Is there a name for the act of plants growing through things like concrete and rocks on their own, independent of weathering?

Comment: Why do you think they are all that different?

Comment: a plant has the same pressure as 200m of water column in plumbing. that's about 10 times more pressure than a tap you can block with your thumb. it's called plants-popping-through-pavements or phytolithic perforation.

Answer (score 1):

*Turgor pressure* is the force within the cell that pushes the plasma membrane against the cell wall.

It is also called *hydrostatic pressure*, the pressure measured by in [fluid when at equilibrium.](https://www.google.fr/search?num=100&q=Turgor%20concrete&oq=Turgor%20concrete&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1378.4455.0.4590.9.9.0.0.0.0.129.776.7j2.9.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.380...0j0i20i263k1j0i22i30k1j0i22i10i30k1.0.BFY2GZceny8)

It's term taught in biology class in school for plants that sag.

I saw a mushroom that had come through a new pavement once. it was cool.

pascal is the atmosphere at sea level:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The pressure inside phloem, the sap in a tree that rises, can be the same as trying to hold shut a hosepipe with your thumb, if the hosepipe water column is 200 meters high. that's why Sequoia trees are only efficient to about 110m high.